# Symfony 3.3 Wrong redirect to login page

Tags: symfony

I create some API. API url's under firewall, and only authenticated users can use them.

Request: PATCH /api/test
Response: No route found for "PATCH /login": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET, POST)

Why redirect with PATCH method?

I use FOSRestBundle and I need json response with access denied message.

security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/cities, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/api/courses, role: ROLE_USER, allow_if: "request.getMethod() == 'GET'" }
```

Comment: You can;t have configured a stateless REST service properly.  Show us your security.yml and route configuration if you want to find out how.

Comment: @Flosculus already update topic

Comment: As @Flosculus states, we really need to see your route configuration too.